# Video Upload using Dot Net Core MVC to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I'm really struggling here as I'm super new to Dot Net Core as well as Google Cloud Storage. I have looked over a lot of the available documentation online but I still can't understand on how to build the architecture.

So what I'm trying to build is a dot net core MVC application that has a form to upload a video file to Google Cloud storage (Google bucket probably?). The controller will take the data from the form and the Model layer is Google Storage.

Some pointers will be really helpful on how can I proceed about this task. Also some links to tutorials or any documentation if you guys think would be useful. Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to get end users to upload files into Google Cloud Storage from their web browser. The trick here is that allowing any random anonymous user write access to your GCS bucket is a bad idea, but you also don't want to require that your users have Google Cloud accounts, either.

To resolve this, Google Cloud Storage offers a feature called "signed URLs." Your server uses its credentials to create a URL that is valid for a limited amount of time and, when presented to GCS by the end user, allows it to do a very specific thing as if it is your application's service account (in this case, uploading an object).

The flow goes like this:

1. Your app signs a URL for uploading an object to GCS and serves it as part of the page to the user.
2. The user does an upload to GCS using whatever JavaScript libraries you prefer.

If you want the user to use a literal POST web form, the signature is a little different than other cases. Look at the "policy document" section here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object#usage_and_examples

Comment: Gotcha, yeah I wasn't even sure where to begin.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample that help answer half your question.  It demonstrates how to upload a file to Google Cloud Storage:
https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/storage/api/Storage/Program.cs#L117

Comment: yeah i have checked this out. Thanks though!